# change the route from post to get if insert an image or use some text-align and

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, production-environment, laravel-10

If I put an align-text or upload an image in the text editor, I simply get the error 405 Method Not Allowed, even though the route is post, the local project, everything is working, but already on the server that I have this problem

I already changed the route, to "match", "any", I already did it by Ajax request, I tweaked the middlewares, I tried to deactivate ModSecurity by htccess, I changed the text editors, I used TinyMCE, CKEDITOR, QUILLJS, TRIX EDITOR, and all with the same problem. If I leave the route with the any or match method, it no longer returns a 405 error, but sends an empty payload;

My Routes:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/new-project', 'BackofficeController@getNewProject')->name('backoffice.new-project');

Route::post('/dashboard/projects', 'BackofficeController@createNewProject')->name('process.create.new.project');
```

My controller:

```php
public function getNewProject()
{
    $project_type = Project_type::all();

    $products = Product::with([
            'sub_category' => function ($query) {
                $query->with([
                    'sub_category_languages' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('language_id', '=', 1);
                    },
                    'category' => function ($query) {
                        $query->with([
                            'category_languages' => function ($query) {
                                $query->where('language_id', '=', 1);
                            }
                        ]);
                    }
                ]);
            }
        ])
        ->where('is_active', '=', true)
        ->where('is_deleted', '=', false)
        ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
        ->get();

    return view('backoffice.new-project', compact('project_type', 'products'));
}

public function createNewProject(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'slug' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'published_at' => 'required | date',
        'is_active' => 'required |boolean',
        'title' => 'required',
        'description'
    ]);
      
    if (Projects::where('slug', request('slug'))->exists()) {
        return back()->with('msg', 'This title already exists')->withInput();
    } else {
        $project = Request([
            'slug' => 'slug',
            'category' => 'category',
            'meta_description' => 'meta_description',
            'key_words' => 'key_words',
            'published_at' => 'published_at',
            'is_active' => 'is_active'
        ]);
         
        // save project in DB
        Projects::create($project);
    }

    $project_languages = Request([
        'title' => 'title',
        'sub_title' => 'sub_title',
        'description' => 'description'
    ]);

    // save project language in DB
    $lastProject = BackofficeRepository::getLastProject();

    $projectId = $lastProject->id;

    $project_languages['projects_id'] = $projectId;

    Projects_languages::create($project_languages);

    // save products relashionatips in DB
    foreach ($request->get('products') as $product_id) {
        $projects_products = new Projects_products();
        $projects_products->product_id = $product_id;
        $projects_products->projects_id = $projectId;

        $projects_products->save();
    }

    // thumbnail image upload
    $path = $request->file('image');

    $custom_name_file = $request->slug . '-' . 'thumbnail' . '.jpg';
    $folder_thumbnail = 'img/inspirations/thumbnails/' .  $request->slug;
    $path->move($folder_thumbnail, $custom_name_file);

    // banners upload
    $files = $request->file('banner');
    $folder_banners = 'img/inspirations/banners/' .  $request->slug;

    if (!empty($files)):
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($files as $file):
            $i++;
            $custom_name_banner = $request->slug . '-' . 'banner' . '-'. $i . '.jpg';
            $file->move($folder_banners, $custom_name_banner);
        endforeach;
    endif;

    return redirect('/dashboard/all-inspirations')->with('msg', 'Project created success!');
```

My form with function ajax (if needed)

```xml
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="col-12 my-3">
                <h3 class="mb-2 text-uppercase" style="color: #89bab6;font-size:2rem !important;text-align:center"><b>Create a new project</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form id="form-create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row m-0">
                        <div class="form-group col-6 pl-0 pr-2">
                            <label for="title">Title:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('title') }}" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Insert title to project" onblur="showSlug()" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-6 pr-0 pl-2">
                            <label for="sub_title">Sub Title:</label>
                            <input type="sub_title" class="form-control" value="{{ old('sub_title') }}" id="sub_title" name="sub_title" placeholder="Insert sub title to project">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group d-none">
                        <label for="slug">Slug:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('slug') }}" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="Insert the slug to project.>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="15" placeholder="Insert your project content">{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="date">Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" value="{{ old('date', date('Y-m-d')) }}" id="published_at" name="published_at" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row m-0">
                        <label for="is_active" class="p-0">Category:</label>
                        @foreach($project_type as $category)
                        <div class="form-group col-4 d-flex">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category" value="{{$category->name}} {{ old('category[]') }}" style="display:block;width:15px">
                            <p class="ml-3 mb-0">{{$category->name}} </p>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="products">Select products:</label>
                        <select class="select-product" required multiple="multiple" name="products[]" id="products" data-live-search="true" data-maximum-selection-length="4">
                            @foreach ($products as $product)
                            <option value="{{$product->id}}">
                                {{$product->name}} {{$product->sub_category->sub_category_languages[0]->name}}
                            </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="meta">Meta Description:</label>
                        <textarea name="meta_description" id="meta_description" cols="30" rows="2" maxlength="200" placeholder="Insert the meta description to project">{{ old('meta_description') }}</textarea>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                            <span id="charCounter1" style="text-transform:lowercase;">200</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="key_words">Key Words:</label>
                        <textarea name="key_words" id="key_words" cols="30" rows="2" maxlength="200" placeholder="Insert the key words to project">{{ old('key_words') }}</textarea>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                            <span id="charCounter2" style="text-transform:lowercase;"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row m-0">
                        <label for="is_active" class="p-0">Project is actived?</label>
                        <div class="form-group col-4 d-flex">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="is_active" id="is_active" onclick="checkedBox(this)" value="1" style="display:block;width:15px" checked>
                            <p class="ml-3 mb-0">Yes</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-4 d-flex">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="is_active" id="is_active" onclick="checkedBox(this)" value="0" style="display:block;width:15px">
                            <p class="ml-3 mb-0">No</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row m-0">
                            <div class="col-8 p-0">
                                <label for="image">Thumbnail image: *please insert a image with dimensions: 850x950</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 px-4">
                                <img src="" alt="" class="preview-img" style="max-width: 89px; max-height: 100px">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="image">Banner image: *please insert a image with dimensions: 500x600 or 1200x600</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="banner" name="banner[]" accept="image/*" multiple required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 m-auto d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <a class="btn-primary btn" href="{{url()->previous()}}" style="border-radius: 0.50rem; padding: 10px 24px"> < BACK </a>
                        <button class="btn bg-gradient-success" type="submit" id="btn-ajax" aria-hidden="true">SAVE</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
@section('footer-scripts')

<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/my9ztv3a3drx46ktolxf8hdqvfrd28mzr2tolcfv2vdwy24u/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn-ajax').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData =  new FormData(document.getElementById("form-create"));

        console.log(formData);
            
        var content = tinymce.get("description").getContent();

        var url = '{{route("process.create.new.project")}}';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response.success)
            },
            error: function(response, error) {
                console.log(response)
                alert(error)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Even if I post directly through Laravel, I have the same problem

I don't know what else to do, can someone please help me?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, if this is **really** a problem related to Laravel 5, you should consider updating it. v5 has left all kinds of support more than two years ago

Comment: Whatever you did to format it like that, try not to do that.